# Downloaded and launched Anaconda. Now how to use pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio, anaconda

I downloaded Anaconda and successfully launched it on my machine. I am using Python 3.6.7 through MS Visual Studio. How do I import the 'pandas' package into my Python console. I am operating on Windows 10.

I have watched a few videos on Youtube and have tried the instructions on the Anaconda website, but I still don't have pandas in Python.

I'm fairly new to Python (3 months experience).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: start Anaconda and run `conda install pandas` then start python and 
`import pandas as pd`

Comment: Thanks for that. It didn't work for me. I launched the CMD.exe prompt and then typed `conda install pandas` into it. It was successful and then I launched Visual Studio and started a new python project and ran `import pandas as pd`. _Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'_

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Visual Studio is using a Python installation that is different from Anaconda.

Try this to see where the Python interpreter is located.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

It should be in the Anaconda installation directory.

Also see this to get your Python interpreter path under Anaconda.
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/

**Windows**

1. From the Start Menu open the Anaconda Prompt.
2. If you want the location of a Python interpreter for a conda environment other than the root conda environment, run `activate environment-name`.
3. Run `where python`.